# Mysql - pivot indeterminate number of rows to multiple columns

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

Given the following two tables:

```
+- Members -+
| ID | Name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Bob  |
|  2 | Jim  |
|  3 | Judy |
etc...
```

This table represents the members' children. Each parent may have many or no children

```
+- Children -------------+-----+
| ID | ParentID | Name   | Age |
+----+----------+--------+-----+
|  1 |      3   | Jeff   |   4 |
|  2 |      3   | Casey  |   3 |
|  3 |      1   | Steven |  10 |
|  4 |      2   | Mary   |   7 |
|  5 |      1   | Esther |   8 |
|  6 |      2   | Abe    |  11 |
|  7 |      3   | Paul   |   6 |
etc...
```

I need to create a table that looks like this:

```
+----+------+--------+------+---------+------+--------+------+
| ID | Name | Child1 | Age1 |  Child2 | Age2 | Child3 | Age3 | 
+----+------+--------+------+---------+------+--------+------+
|  1 | Bob  | Steven |  10  | Esther  |   8  |        |      |
|  2 | Jim  | Abe    |  11  | Mary    |   7  |        |      |
|  3 | Judy | Paul   |   6  | Jeff    |   4  | Casey  |   3  |
+----+------+--------+------+---------+------+--------+------+
```

I've tried various pivot table approaches, but every one that I've seen requires a known number of rows in the second table for each row in the first table. **I essentially need an unknown number of columns.** A `group_concat` isn't going to meet my requirements.

Is this possible with MySQL or do I need to do this in the backend?

Comment: Try searching for dynamic mysql pivot.

Comment: This kind of thing is relatively straightforward in application-level code (e.g. a PHP loop acting upon an ordered array)